# It is possible to show at least one decoration view in a empty UICollectionView?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Well, i have one custom UICollection that is a bookshelf. 
Even if my objects array is empty (book covers) , i wanna show at least one "empty" shelf.

How it is possible?

Thanks!

---

**[UPDATE]** My solution:

Maybe its not the best way, but for me works like a charm. I tryed to verify if in my UICollectionReusableView class had some method to do this but I didn't have success. So, I tryed another way using the collectionView methods.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //even the array of elements was empty, return at least 1 fake book
    if(_books.count == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return _books.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    CellCollection *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CUSTOM_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setHidden:YES]; // not show any items by default

    // If exist elements 
    if(_books.count != 0){
        [cell setHidden:NO]; // shows the items

        ..... // config the cell properties
        .......
    }

    return cell;
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // only if the selected element exist
    if(_books[indexPath.row]){

        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`. Then in that method, call super, and add your decoration view layout attributes to the array.

Comment: This is very unspecific. Please add supporting code and details.

Comment: I think this is detailed enough. If OP can't get it to work I'd be happy to assist then. SO is not about spitting out code, it's about providing assistance.

Comment: I would argue that SO is about providing assistance to everyone, not just to the OP. I had the same question myself, and your answer didn't provide enough detail to help me, so I'm guessing other people might have the same issue. In your defense, it's hard to give a detailed answer to a poorly-detailed question.